# UIPopoverControllerView root view padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, padding, margin, popover

[image]

[image]

[image]

As seen in the image
As rootview goes up to the top of the arrow
The top of the button is cut off.

### How to fix it?

```
- (IBAction)actionAddChatBtn:(id)sender {
    UIButton *view = (UIButton *)sender;

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    ChatTypePopupViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"choose_chattype_popup"];
    vc.chatTypePopupDelegate = self;

    [self presentPopOverWithViewController:vc sourceView:view];
}

- (void)presentPopOverWithViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController sourceView:(UIView *)sourceView {
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    viewController.preferredContentSize = viewController.view.bounds.size; 

    UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController = viewController.popoverPresentationController;
    presentationController.delegate = self;
    presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
    presentationController.sourceView = sourceView;
    presentationController.sourceRect = sourceView.bounds;

    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Change the y position for three buttons. If doesn't work. Please share code to help.

Comment: For reference, the top space is not set so that the top is not cut.